# IntelliJ Debug Window Layout

Tags: intellij-idea

I have moved the Debug tool frame to the right side of my layout.  This is nice except for one problem.  The layout of the tabs internal to the tool (i.e. Frames, Variables, Watches) are laid out horizontally.  The result is that I cannot see the Frames and Variables tabs at the same time because there just isn't enough room.  This would work fine if I could simply layout the tabs vertically, so that Frames sits just above the Variables tab.

I have looked all over to find a setting that would allow this, but I can't find it.  Is it possible?  Perhaps it is not.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Just drafted the question to post and then saw this. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is a feature of IntelliJ.  I don't see it in IntelliJ 12.  Since it's a community-driven IDE, you could always make a [feature request of it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) and see how well it takes.

Comment: Bummer, but that's how it goes sometimes. :(

Comment: @ViperBailey, have you raised a feature request already for this?

Comment: If you do, then post the link to the feature request.  I'll happily give it a +1.